# Extended Keyboard Shortcut Commands

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have the following command I would like to bind to keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu:

`node ~/Executables/harmonyHubCLI/harmonyHubCli.js -l 10.0.0.59 -d 'Samsung TV' -c 'InputHdmi3'`

which works fine in a terminal session. However, using this command in the keyboard shortcut setup GUI does not yield any results - yet, if I change the command to something like "nautilus", it works fine. I tried double quotes around the entire command as well - same result.

Is this sort of thing not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using AutoKey and works perfectly